# Можно ли сделать цикл for без шага?

Tags: javascript

Цикл for состоит из тела, начала, условия и шага. А можно сделать без шага?

Comment: эм, расскажи а зачем тогда тебе цикл, и что это за кейс когда тебе нужен цикл без цикла

Comment: `while()` и есть тот самый цикл без шага. Зачем вам `for()`?

Comment: Нет. Синтаксис `for` не позволяет такого

Comment: `for(;;);` — Можно запустить вот прямо в таком виде... получится бесконечный цикл)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В принципе, любая часть в классическом цикле for может быть опущена или перемещена в тело, если вы понимаете, что делаете и как это повлияет на поведение цикла. Но читабельность может пострадать, так как читатель привык к обычному набору частей и может быть озадачен. Например, шаг может быть совмещён с проверкой и пропущен, но чтобы это понять, будет потрачена лишняя секунда)

```js
for (let i = 5; i-- > 0; ) console.log(i);
```